# How can I connect with an Oracle 8i database through a Python 3.6 code?

Tags: python, oracle

I wanna connect to Oracle 8i Database using Python2.7 or Python3.6 as I am not an Oracle guy so I need your help on this.

**I am having following scenario:**

1. My Database server is located at remote location.
2. I have to connect with that database through either version of Python2.7 or Python3.6.
3. After connection I just wants to do as normal queries.

**Things which I have already done is:**

1. cx_Oracle library 6.2 version installed.
2. Oracle instant Client libraries installed and using these libraries I am able to connect from Oracle 9i to Oracle 12c.
3. Now I just wants to make connection with Oracle 8i database.

thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I guess `oracle 8` is not supported in `6.2` ... https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/

Comment: Oracle 8i is about twenty years old. It has been out of support for a decade. Obviously as a standalone database it remains functional but integration with something so old will always be a challenge. Anyway, Oracle's backwards compatibility has always been pretty good. So have you tried connecting to your 8i database with the 9i setup?

Answer (score 0):

Uh, Oracle 8 ... where did you manage to find that fossil?

Anyway: [this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Oracle) says that you should use "OJDBC and JayDeBeApi" which works with databases

> supported by Oracle's JDBC drivers (currently 8.1.7 to 11.2.0.2.0)

There's some more info, so - have a look.